# Distorting one corner of a sculpted wall

Tags: distort

I am completely new to Blender and only know a few basic things. I have a problem that I cannot figure out. I basically need to take a long rectangular 3D wall and distort only one corner of it so the top line becomes a diagonal line. In photoshop, the tool is called "distort", not WARP. You can basically grab one corner and distort it while the other 3 corners stay in tact. Is this even possible in Blender? Please help if you can. Note: I did this sample photo in Photoshop so it's a little different. Thank you in advance, Brian

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you edit the title to be more specific. It sounds like you just want to go into Edit Mode, click on the corner and move it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any Distort tool in Blender since mesh is not an image and it can't be transformed that easily however you can work with modifiers and edit mesh data depending on another mesh, basically transforming one according to vertices of another one.

**First prepare the dummy mesh which will be used as a cage**

Add a cube or extruded plane (since in your case wall object is flat surface) and scale it so that it roughly matches your wall but is slightly bigger. Note that dummy object has to be closed one (no holes and preferably as little details as possible; default cube should do fine). Position it on the same place as your high density wall object (like when baking normals to lowpoly).

**Then grab the high density mesh you have and add a Mesh Deform modifier to it**

Since it requires vertex group enter Edit mode, select all vertices and add them to new vertex group (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

Then in modiifier settings choose that vertex group, select dummy object to act as transforming cage.

**Finally in Mesh Deform modifier settings click Bind**

Note that this operation can take a while depending on mesh complexity and hardware resources you have.

Then once it's binded in Object mode select cage object, enter Edit mode for it, select vertices in one corner (to match your example) and grab them towards another corner. High density mesh will follow their transformation.

[image]

Note that additionally you can hook vertices of the cage object (cube) to an empty  and grab empty in Object mode in order to skip entering Edit mode for the cage (which can be computational heavy operation).

See more about [Mesh Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/mesh_deform.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Switch from "Object Mode" to "Edit mode" at the bottom of the screen, click on the corner, and use the arrows to move it.
[image]

Comment: I am so sorry. I should have been more clear. I actually have a 3D rock wall with many many polygons.

Comment: Go into sculpt mode (same place as edit), click on the sphere at the top right and click on the option named "F Grab." Then click on the symmetry dropdown, and make sure X, Y, and Z are unselected. You can zoom out or change the number underneath "Grab" to chage the size of the area. Then click+drag the area you want to extend.